# Allow a windows exel addin(.xll) file under windows defender

Tags: excel-addins, malware, windows-defender

I have a excel addin plugin(.xll) that is getting blocked due to windows defender. So how to set exclusion for this file since this file is a part of a msi package which will be deployed at client machines and asking the client to add a exclusion in their security policy group will not be possible.

This .xll file is digitally signed from veried source too

When windows defender block this file following alert box shows up and the file is deleted from directory
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
PS > Add-MpPreference -ExclusionExtension ".xll"
```

More info and options in the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/configure-extension-file-exclusions-microsoft-defender-antivirus?view=o365-worldwide